# The error type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'bool' in Woo commerce VendorShippingMethodModel

Tags: android, wordpress, flutter, woocommerce

The Flutter app is integrated with woocommerce backend

and throwing below error

The following _TypeError was thrown building Consumer(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedTheme, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#de082], _InheritedProviderScope<VendorShippingMethodModel?>]):
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'bool'

[image]

Comment: Could you post the specific model that is giving you an error. It is a TypeError, so it seems that an attribute you have declared as `bool` should be `bool?`.

Comment: I have integrated the woocommerce with flutter, it was working fine, and when I configure for other woo-commerce flutter code is working fine, some settings or error in backend configuration,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my flutter app was integrated with Woocommerce
in my case, I have added the below code in evn.dart file and solved the issue

```
"advanceConfig":{
  "EnableDeliveryDateOnCheckout":true,"EnableNewSmsLogin":false
```